# Multiple pages iframe with onload for height

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe that includes a script with multiple pages and I want to adjust the height of this iframe automatically according to the content height. It works correctly when I load the first page but when I change to another one, the function is called again but the height is the same even if the content is not the same height on every pages.

The javascript function:

```
function autoResize(id){
  var newheight;

  if(document.getElementById){
      newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
  }

  document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
}
```

And my iframe:

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="myScript" width="950px" onLoad="autoResize('iframe');"></iframe>
```

When I add `alert(newheight)` after it's set using `contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight`, I get the alert on each page but the height is always the same. 
Is there another way to get the current iframe content height?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this function, pass `iframe` id for on every iframe load, `iframe id` should be unique

```
    function autoResize(frameId){
        var F = document.getElementById(frameId);
        if(F.contentDocument) {
            F.height = F.contentDocument.documentElement.scrollHeight; //FF 3.0.11, Opera 9.63, and Chrome
        } else {
            F.height = F.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight; //IE6, IE7 and Chrome    
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get the same outcome. The first page height is correctly displayed but when I change the page, the height stays the same.

Comment: How you are change the page in frame ?

Comment: Every pages use the same php script and the only difference between pages is the `LIMIT` in the SQL query.

Comment: Did you change iframe id dynamically ? If php genertae the iframe means, you need to generate unique iframe id and supplied into the `autoResize()` function

Comment: The iframe id doesn't change. The iframe is not generated by PHP, the content of the iframe is.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot since this is work related and the PHP script is not from me but I have access to the code and the only difference from one page to the other is the `LIMIT` used in the SQL query.

Comment: Assume, you have mutipage document, if you select 2 or 3rd page, you need to resize your frame according to the page size right ?

Comment: Exactly. But even if the function is correctly called when I change the page, the height is the same even if the content height is not.

Comment: While switch between pages, you need to call this function from there itself

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function autoResize(id){
    var n1=id.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
    document.getElementById(id).style.height = n1 + 'px';
}
```

Comment: @oliboon are u changing the page by a link inside the iframe?

Comment: Every pages use the same php script and the only difference between pages is the LIMIT in the SQL query.

Comment: By pages do u mean within the iframe?

Comment: Yes. The parent window doesn't change, it's only the iframe content that changes.

Comment: you are using onload event handler.So the javascript function is called only at the start when the page containing iframe loads.With change in content inside iframe the function is not called.

Comment: That is what I find strange because if I had `alert('test')` in the autoResize function, I will receive this alert everytime I change the page.

Comment: try using onload together with onchange event